# How do I avoid calling part of my string as a command?

Tags: bash

I run with the file with command line arguments:
`samplebash.bsh fakeusername fakepassword&123`

.bsh file:

```
echo "Beginning script..."
argUsername='$1'
argPassword='$2'
protractor indv.js --params.login.username=$argUsername --params.login.password=$argPassword
```

Output:

> Beginning script...
>
> 123: command not found

**The Issue:** For some reason, it interprets what follows the & symbol from the password as a command, how do I avoid this?

Comment: Enclose it in quotes

Comment: Why are you quoting the variables in your assignments? That prevents expanding them.

Comment: Learn to check you code at http://shellcheck.net before posting. (Include `#!/bin/bash` as the first line.) The explanations are a little opaque for beginners, but focus on the exact line and char position it is pointing to and research similar working code to figure out why yours isn't working. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't happening in your script, it's happening in your original command line. `&` is a command terminator, which specifies that the command before it should be executed in the background. So your command was equivalent to:

```
samplebash.bsh fakeusername fakepassword &
123
```

You need to quote the argument to prevent special characters from being interpreted by the shell.

```
samplebash.bsh fakeusername 'fakepassword&123'
```

Also, you shouldn't put single quotes around a variable like you do in your assignments, that prevents the variable from being expanded. So it should be:

```
argUsername=$1
argPassword=$2
```

And you should put double quotes around the variables when you use them in the command, to prevent wildcards and whitespace from being interpreted.

```
protractor indv.js --params.login.username="$argUsername" --params.login.password="$argPassword"
```

As a general rule, you should always put double quotes around variables unless you know they're not needed.